# WSO2 ESB does not return error code in case of endpoint failure

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a proxy service in WSO2 ESB which is listening over a Queue via JMS and then after some processing it sends message to another queue. It works fine. I am implementing fault sequence of this service that in case if endpoint is suspended then it should send message to an error queue. In fault sequence WSO2 ESB is generating ERROR_MESSAGE, ERROR_DETAIL, ERROR_EXCEPTION but it is not generating ERROR_CODE.

**Fault Sequence:**

```
<faultSequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <log level="full" separator="**********Fault Sequence File Processor***********">
      <property name="ErrorCode" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"></property>
      <property name="ErrorMessage" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"></property>
      <property name="ErrorDetail" expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"></property>
      <property name="ErrrorException" expression="get-property('ERROR_EXCEPTION')"></property>
   </log>
   <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
      <format>
         <MessageFormat xmlns="">
            <ECode>$1</ECode>
            <EMsg>$2</EMsg>
            <EDetail>$3</EDetail>
            <EException>$4</EException>
         </MessageFormat>
      </format>
      <args>
         <arg expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')" evaluator="xml"></arg>
         <arg expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')" evaluator="xml"></arg>
         <arg expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')" evaluator="xml"></arg>
         <arg expression="get-property('ERROR_EXCEPTION')" evaluator="xml"></arg>
      </args>
   </payloadFactory>
   <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
   <property name="ClientApiNonBlocking" action="remove" scope="axis2"></property>
   <send>
      <endpoint key="conf:/endpoints/ErrorQueue.xml"></endpoint>
   </send>
</faultSequence>
```

**Endpoint Which i am suspending:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Endpoint">
    <address uri="jms:/RequestQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://192.168.1.33:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue" format="pox">
<timeout>
            <duration>6000</duration>
        </timeout>

        <markForSuspension>
            <errorCodes>101504, 101505, 303001, 303000</errorCodes>
            <retriesBeforeSuspension>1</retriesBeforeSuspension>
            <retryDelay>1</retryDelay>
        </markForSuspension>

        <suspendOnFailure>
            <errorCodes>101500, 101501, 101506, 101507, 101508, 303001, 303000</errorCodes>
            <initialDuration>1000</initialDuration>
            <progressionFactor>2</progressionFactor>
            <maximumDuration>6400</maximumDuration>
        </suspendOnFailure>


</address>


</endpoint>
```

**Note:**
The **IP** mentioned in the **"address"** URI is not correct so that's why service goes into fault sequence.

**Output on Error Queue:**

```
<MessageFormat><ECode>0</ECode><EMsg>Unexpected error during sending message out</EMsg><EDetail>org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unexpected error during sending message out
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.handleException(Axis2Sender.java:172)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:338)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:333)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.IndirectEndpoint.send(IndirectEndpoint.java:54)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:196)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.Target.mediate(Target.java:106)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.splitter.IterateMediator.mediate(IterateMediator.java:146)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:196)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:166)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.handleIncomingMessage(AbstractTransportListener.java:328)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.processFile(VFSTransportListener.java:597)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.scanFileOrDirectory(VFSTransportListener.java:328)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Unable to create a JMSMessageSender for : null
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.handleException(AbstractTransportSender.java:226)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:129)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:297)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:482)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:59)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://192.168.1.33:61616. Reason: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:301)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:246)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:203)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.createJMSSender(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:363)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:127)
        ... 39 more
</EDetail><EException></EException></MessageFormat>
```

**Problem:**
Why WSO2 ESB does not generate ERROR_CODE? I have to get that error code and on the basis of error code make some further logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default behaviour of WSO2 ESB. In Endpoint failure case, WSO2 ESB returns 0 as ErrorCode but Error Detail and Error Message have specific error messages. What you can do is, using Filter mediator or Switch mediator you can make your custom error code and message.

```
<filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" source="json-eval($.node[0].nid)" regex="100">
      <then>
        //your business here
      </then>
      <else>
        //your business here
      </else>
  </filter>
```